# Inline command execution in PowerShell ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell

I am familiar with how BASH syntax handles this request but I am unable to find a way to do this in PowerShell.

BASH Example:

```
for x in `ls .`; do something with ${x}; done
```

What I am trying to perform the same thing with PowerShell (which has the incorrect syntax for demonstration purposes)...

```
ForEach ($group in `$wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups()`)
```

...I obviously get a syntax error.

BASH to PowerShell translation is the ask here. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the example you have, it would just work (without the backticks):

```
ForEach ($group in $wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups()) {
    # do stuff
}
```

If it's a command, you can wrap it in a subexpression:

```
foreach ($process in $(Get-Process)) {
    # do stuff
}
```

You might also look at the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet which can be more idiomatic in PowerShell's pipelines:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "This process is $_" -Verbose }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get going...

```
$things = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\

foreach ($thing in $things) {
    # Do a thing with each one in turn
    Write-Host $thing.Name -ForegroundColor Magenta
}
```